# Tracking down null-reference error in Windows Service Application - whats going on here?

Tags: .net, exception, service

I'm making a data-adapter service, and i need to take a backup of the affected tables before messing with the data. I'm using calling the external process "mysqldump.exe" and everything works fine from a command-line - but the service throws a null-reference error when initiating a backup.

As you can see in the code, I've tried very hard to pinpoint where the error happens (the exception is caught and written to the Windows Application Log in my controller layer), but none of my own Exceptions gets thrown, so I end up none-the-wiser.

here we go:

```
public static string Backup(string host, string database, string dbUser, string dbPwd, string[] tables, string OutputFile, out bool succes, string fileRoot)
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        int debug = 0;
        try
        {
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fileRoot + "Backup\\mysqldump.exe";
            debug++;
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            debug++;
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            debug++;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            debug++;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            debug++;
            succes = false;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("BackupMetoden blev afbrud ved en fejl under instantieringen af mysqldump.exe\r\n\r\nDebug niveau: " + debug);
        }
        //Rediger Arguments
        debug = 0;
        string output = "";
        try
        {
            string args = "-h " + host + " " + database + "  --tables #TABELLER#" + "--user=" + dbUser + " --password=" + dbPwd + " --result-file " + OutputFile;
            debug++;
            string tabeller = "";
            debug++;
            foreach (string t in tables)
            { tabeller += t + " "; }
            debug++;
            args = args.Replace("#TABELLER#", tabeller);
            debug++;
            myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
            debug++;
            output = "Ingen backup udført - der er sket en fejl";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("BackupMetoden blev afbrud ved en fejl under samling af kommando-syntaks\r\n" + ex.Message + "\r\nDebug niveau: " + debug);
        }

        try
        {
            myProcess.Start();
            output = myProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            succes = true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            succes = false;
            throw new Exception("Der opstod en fejl under backup: " + output + "\r\n" + ex.Message + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

I know for sure that the error is thrown within the code above, because the Exception is wrapped in a message by the calling method:

```
try
        {
            resultat = VDB_MysqlBackupRestore.Backup(indstillinger.Host(kilde), indstillinger.DB(kilde), indstillinger.User(kilde), indstillinger.Pass(kilde), tables, outputFile, out succes, rodmappe);
            return resultat;
        }
catch (Exception backupfejl)
        {
            throw new Exception("Der opstod fejl under uførelsen af backup i controller-laget: " + backupfejl.Message);
        }
```

...And the wrapping message shows up in the application-log like this:

*Der opstod fejl under uførelsen af backup i controller-laget: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

I'm building it in Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows 7 32bit. It's been tested both locally and on a Windows 2008 Web server with the same result. I'm using the .net 4 framework

Comment: You know, an exception object also has a stacktrace, might be useful to pinpoint the exact location. Better yet, include your original exception as innerException when re-throwing, so the stacktrace wont get lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the object `indstillinger` is null, or some of its internal things and when you try to use it, it throws an `NullReferenceException`.

Try to run this in a Console application and step through the code and you'll spot the error.

Or even better, have a look at the [Topshelf project](http://topshelf-project.com/) and implement your Windows service using that. It's a much more pleasant way to develop Windows Services.

Comment: You were absolutely right, the indstillinger-object was the problem, i had simply stared myself blind on the issue. Topshelf looks great, I'll be sure to look into it further!

Answer (score 1):

you are catching the exceptions in a very wrong way, inside the catch block if you really want to create a new exception and throw it, don't create a new base Exception but an `ApplicationException` or other derived class from `Exception` and make sure you pass to such constructor call the actual exception of the catch block, like `ex`; you should pass the ex object not only the ex.Message or you are going to hide the real exception and all its properties like callstack, inner exception and so on....